# Get maximum relative difference between row-values and row-mean in new pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, mean, difference

I want to have an extra column with the maximum relative difference [-] of the row-values and the mean of these rows:

The df is filled with energy use data for several years.
The theoretical formula that should get me this is as follows:
**df['max_rel_dif'] = MAX [ ABS(highest energy use – mean energy use), ABS(lowest energy use – mean energy use)] / mean energy use**

**Initial dataframe:**

```
   ID  y_2010   y_2011   y_2012  y_2013  y_2014
0  23   22631  21954.0  22314.0   22032   21843
1  43   27456  29654.0  28159.0   28654    2000
2  36   61200      NaN      NaN   31895    1600
3  87   87621  86542.0  87542.0   88456   86961
4  90   58951  57486.0   2000.0       0       0
5  98   24587  25478.0      NaN   24896   25461
```

**Desired dataframe:**

```
   ID  y_2010   y_2011   y_2012  y_2013  y_2014  max_rel_dif
0  23   22631  21954.0  22314.0   22032   21843      0.02149
1  43   27456  29654.0  28159.0   28654    2000      0.91373
2  36   61200      NaN      NaN   31895    1600      0.94931
3  87   87621  86542.0  87542.0   88456   86961      0.01179
4  90   58951  57486.0   2000.0       0       0      1.48870
5  98   24587  25478.0      NaN   24896   25461      0.02065
```

tried code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [23,43,36,87,90,98],    
               "y_2010": [22631,27456,61200,87621,58951,24587],    
               "y_2011": [21954,29654,np.nan,86542,57486,25478],     
               "y_2012": [22314,28159,np.nan,87542,2000,np.nan],      
               "y_2013": [22032,28654,31895,88456,0,24896,],            
               "y_2014": [21843,2000,1600,86961,0,25461]})  

print(df)  

a = df.loc[:, ['y_2010','y_2011','y_2012','y_2013', 'y_2014']]

  # calculate mean 
mean = a.mean(1) 

# calculate max_rel_dif
df['max_rel_dif'] = (((df.max(axis=1).sub(mean)).abs(),(df.min(axis=1).sub(mean)).abs()).max()).div(mean) 

    # AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'max'
-> I'm obviously doing the wrong thing with the tuple, I just don't know how to get the maximum values
   from the tuples and divide them then by the mean in the proper Phytonic way
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the whole function can be

```
s=df.filter(like='y')
s.sub(s.mean(1),axis=0).abs().max(1)/s.mean(1)
0    0.021494
1    0.913736
2    0.949311
3    0.011800
4    1.488707
5    0.020653
dtype: float64
```